# Cycles transition effect doesn't show in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

We followed this tutorial with a simple t-shirt and it worked perfectly with cycles.

Then we did it with a dress that has different materials and it doesn't show the effect when we want to render it. Do you maybe have a solution?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rWGVzIKKGc

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/870364990136270958/908820326266310726/2021-11-12_15-44-15.mp4

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: generally due to something that is disabled for rendering. Either object visibility or a modifier...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.